# ip xfrm policy port

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipsec

On Linux, `ip xfrm policy` let's me specify the selector on which I want to enable IPsec.  It allows you to restrict IPsec to a particular port, by specifying `[ sport PORT ] [ dport PORT ]`

I would like to enable IPsec for all but one port.  E.g. IPsec for all ports *except* 873.  Is there any way to do that? Is there any way to specify a "not" in the SELECTOR? If not, what is the workaround?

Note that I am referring to manual initialization of the kernel's IPsec, using the `ip xfrm` command.

Answer (score 1):

Just create passthrough policies for that port that have a higher `priority` (lower numeric value) than the policies that match all ports. Passthrough policies have `action allow` but no templates attached.

> Without docs, I would have expected that allow simply allows the traffic, not that it bypasses the other policies and skips encrypting it.

That's because the Linux kernel stores the policies in a list ordered by priority and only uses the first matching policy. So if an `action allow` policy (the default, the only other option is to use `action drop` to filter traffic) without templates (i.e. without any instructions how to process/encrypt the traffic) has a higher priority than the actual IPsec policies the traffic will just bypass IPsec processing.

For instance, if your existing policies have priority 1000 then add passthrough policies for TCP port 873 like this:

```
ip xfrm policy add proto tcp sport 873 dport 873 dir out priority 1
ip xfrm policy add proto tcp sport 873 dport 873 dir in priority 1
```

The priority could be anything, it must just be lower than 1000 so traffic matches these policies first.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea.  I'm not familiar with passthrough policies or with priorities.  Could you give an example that will do what you described?

Comment: And, the ip xfrm docs mention `action allow` in the grammar but include zero text describing what it does.  Without docs, I would have expected that `allow` simply _allows_ the traffic, not that it bypasses the other policies and skips encrypting it.  Google isn't able to find an example of `action allow` like this either.

Answer (score 0):

You config one policy which protects all ports, and config another policy with higher priority which allows one certain port.
It looks like this:

```
ip xfrm policy add src 194.168.10.4 dst 194.168.10.5 dir out tmpl src 194.168.10.4 dst 194.168.10.5 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 194.168.10.5 dst 194.168.10.4 dir in tmpl src 194.168.10.5 dst 194.168.10.4 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add proto tcp dport 8088 dir  in action allow priority 1    
ip xfrm policy add proto tcp sport 8088 dir  out action allow priority 1
```